# Method signature for variable length of arguments

Tags: python

I would like to create a method that a tuple followed by 2 keyword argument one or several times, followed by other keyword arguments.
For exemple:

```
funct(data_1, x='x_val', y='y_val', data_2, x='x_val', y='y_val',
data_3, x='x_val', y='y_val', other_args='other_args_val')
```

or

```
funct(data_1, x='x_val', y='y_val', data_2, x='x_val', y='y_val',
data_3, x='x_val', y='y_val')
```

or

```
funct(data_1, x='x_val', y='y_val')
```

or

```
funct(data_1, x='x_val', y='y_val', other_args='other_args_val')
```

would be valid calls, where data_1, data_2, data_3 are tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make functions that accept any number of keyword arguments:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    pass
```

As you can see, this will not let you do what you want.

```
foo(x=None, x=None)
#>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
#>>>   File "<string>", line 73, in <module>
#>>>   File "/usr/lib/python3.3/ast.py", line 35, in parse
#>>>     return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
#>>>   File "<unknown>", line 4
#>>> SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated
```

Your only choice is to make a new input mechanism. I suggest `data, dictionary, data, dictionary, data, dictionary, ...`:

```
def funct(*args):
    ...

funct(
    data1, {"x": "x_val", "y": "y_val"},
    data2, {"x": "x_val", "y": "y_val"},
    data3, {"x": "x_val", "y": "y_val", "other_args": "other_args_val"}
)
```

Alternatively you can accept class instances (possible `namedtuple`):

```
funct(
    Data(data1, x="x_val", y="y_val"),
    Data(data2, x="x_val", y="y_val"),
    Data(data3, x="x_val", y="y_val", other_args="other_args_val")
)
```

Comment: And there would not other way to have each of my tuples arguments associated with x and y arguments ?

Comment: These are the best ways I know of.

Comment: Ok thank you, i'll try with the named tuple, it should do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Python. keyword args are passed into a dict, so must be unique

Answer (score 0):

You could, as Veedrac suggests, pass `*args` to the function, but instead the arguments themselves are tuples. When you iterate over the arguments you can unpack them as so:

```
def func(*args):
    for (data,x,y) in args:
        print data,x,y

# Pass a few tuples
func( ('cat',1,2), ('dog',3,5), ('foo',9,-1) )
```

giving

```
cat 1 2
dog 3 5
foo 9 -1
```

Any other `args` that don't fit in the pattern could be placed in a dict `**kwargs` if needed. A more robust answer would be to create a class or a `namedtuple` as suggested by the others comments.